# Laptop shuts down instead of going into sleep mode when I send it to sleep

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, troubleshooting, sleep, power-management

I'm using an Asus laptop. It's more than a year old. This has been going on for maybe a month. I've looked into all the basic settings but can't find what's causing the problem. Here are the settings:

[image]

And I also tried changing what the power button does when on battery power to see if that will work, but the computer still refuses to go into sleep mode and instead shuts down when I press the power button - and I should add that the 45 minute rule is followed on batter power also, but only with the variation that the laptop is shut down, and not sent to sleep:

[image]

Comment: Mark, why don't you try to change "When I press power button" to Sleep When plugged in? and then try.. if it sleeps then you can change your direction of investigation to why your laptop is not able to identify whether it is on battery or plugged in.

Comment: Which model exactly? On some laptops the power button is hardcoded in the BIOS/UEFI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem that needs solving is that chkdsk never finishes.
Once the disk is verified, it is possible to check the integrity of Windows
using [sfc /scannow](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/3047-sfc-scannow-command-run-windows-8-a.html).

You may try to leave chkdsk running overnight, but if this never finishes,
try to see if one of the following tools can find the error :

- [EaseUS Partition Master Free](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) doing [disk surface test](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/disk-surface-test.htm)
- [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/files/hdtune_255.exe) doing Error scan
- [Macroit Free Disk Scanner](http://macrorit.com/disk-surface-test/disk-surface-test.html)

Comment: Chdsk finished running when I left it on to run all night. They I ran the sfc scan. It finished with reporting some corrupt files that it wasn't able to fix. I'm now going to restart and run the scan again as instructed on the link. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

Can you navigate to system recovery settings? If you don't know how follow these instructions :

1. Hold `winkey+r` to bring up a Run box
2. Type `sysdm.cpl` hit Enter
3. Select Advanced Tab
4. System StartUp and Recovery, Settings
5. Under system failure make sure Automatically Restart is **NOT** checked
6. Under dump file make sure it says `%SystemRoot%\MEMORY.DMP`

Select Ok then try your screen/sleep again.

### Method 2

If this doesn't work and you laptop still restarts, follow the next steps:

1. Hold `winkey+R` to bring up Run box
2. Type `msconfig` hit Enter
3. On the General tab check Selective start up and uncheck Load start
   up items
4. Now go into Services tab and select Hide Microsoft Services then
   click Disable all
5. Select Ok and restart your computer.

Then try to enter sleep mode again by closing the lid.

### Method 3

If you are still not having any luck, I would give this a try first and if it doesn't work then reset your power settings to Never sleep:

1. Open Command Prompt in Admin mode and type `chkdsk /f/r`
   This will take a while to complete but let it run fully
2. You will be prompted that it cannot run this as it is currently
   being used, would you like to run it on next start. **Choose Y**
3. Then restart your system.

See if your computer still restarts.

Comment: Methods 1 didn't work. Number 2 worked but then the wifi and stuff were disabled so had to reverse changes. On 3, I was stuck at 20% for two hours. I had to force a restart but the scan started again and stuck again. I'm not sure how to fix it now as its left the computer useless. Help?

Comment: I'm back. Had to spend half an hour trying to figure out how to get out of the whole restart/scan-up-to-20% loop. They give you only one second to skip the scan which I completely missed seeing for the first two times. Anyway, the scan wasn't completed but sleep mode works now. I've checked it twice. Not completely satisfied though because I can't see what was causing the problem to begin with, and how it got fixed now, if it even is fixed for good.

Comment: @Mark: The chkdsk must finish. If it doesn't, then there is a serious problem with the disk. After it finishes correctly, check also [sfc /scannow](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/3047-sfc-scannow-command-run-windows-8-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc Well it was stuck for over an hour at 20% so I decided it was best to stop. How long does this process usually take? Maybe I can let it run over night and see. There doesn't seem to be any problems with the disk, however. Computer functions smoothly. Say there are issues, what then?

Comment: I added my own answer so as not to hijack this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having problems with `chkdsk`, this may help:

Open an elevated command prompt:

Search for `cmd.exe` (Windows Command Processor), or **Command Prompt**. Right-click Command Prompt, and then click **Run as administrator**.

[Type the following command:](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833)

> `sfc /scannow`

After the process is finished, reboot your computer.

Open an elevated command prompt and [type the following command:](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947821)

> `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`