# When put to sleep, laptop force shuts down then restarts

Tags: windows-10, sleep

When I put my laptop to sleep, it unexpectedly force shuts down then turns back on.

I know that it is a force shutdown as Event Viewer reports that the computer shutdown unexpectedly.

This occurred after updating to Windows 10 2004. Is there a fix?

Comment: Check if page file is set to be disabled. That can have that effect.

Comment: Page file is enabled

Comment: Do you have an AMD GPU and witch one if you have it?

Comment: No, NVIDIA GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem might occur due to incorrect power settings. You can try below mentioned fixes.

FIX 1 – Restore Default Power Plan

1. Right click battery or power icon on taskbar, select Power Options.
2. In Power Options window, under Selected plan, click on Change plan settings link.
3. Finally, in Edit Plan Settings window, click on Restore default settings for this plan link.
4. On the confirmation prompt appeared next, click Yes and this should restore  default power plan for the machine.
   You can now verify and see if the issue still persists. If yes, go ahead with FIX 2.

FIX 2 – Verify Power & Sleep Button Settings

1. Right click battery icon on taskbar, select Power Options.
2. Next, in Power Options window, click Choose what closing the lid does link.
3. Now set all the Power and sleep buttons and lid settings to Sleep or Hibernate for every case. Click Save changes.

If the issue still persists, please check if methods in the following similar thread were helpful.
[Laptop shuts down instead of going into sleep mode when I send it to sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/961667/laptop-shuts-down-instead-of-going-into-sleep-mode-when-i-send-it-to-sleep)